# Replace images by serving through PHP script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to serve all my images through a PHP script. Ultimately the goal is to replace the images dynamically if certain conditions are met, but for now I'm just trying to get the script to return a specific image file. I've got a .htaccess which is sending all image requests to this script but at the moment the image is not showing up on the page.

Full contents of PHP script:

```
$img = '/imgs/img1.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($img));
readfile($img);
```

I want to get URL of the image request that was redirected to this script. Depending on conditions I want to either serve the image immediately or use the image to generate a new one with GD and return that.

Comment: Why download the image over HTTP?  Why not serve it from disk at this point?  You probably don't have the HTTP fopen wrapper enabled.  You can also 302 redirect to the image, depending on your needs.

Comment: I agree, give a relative path to the image instead.

Comment: Changed the file path to /imgs/img1.jpg but still doesn't work

Comment: You are giving a path to the location in the hard drive not the docroot. Therefore, unless the file in located in your hard drive in /imgs/ it wont work.

Comment: How do you know the redirection in .htaccess is working? Maybe it isn't.

Comment: @Ares Thanks for the hint. Changed to $img = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/imgs/img1.jpg'; and it works. Think I need to read up on Apache.

Comment: Posted an answer for people coming back later with the same problem. You should accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving a path to the location in the hard drive not the docroot. Therefore, unless the file in located in your hard drive in /imgs/ it wont work. Try:

```
$img = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/imgs/img1.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($img));
readfile($img);
```